# SQL Server datetime sorting but need to display only date part

Tags: sql-server

I have a table employee with this structure:

```
emp#     empName     transDate
--------------------------------------------
101       aaaa       2016-03-01 15:41:48.417 
102       bbbb       2016-01-01 15:41:48.417 
103       cccc       2016-02-01 15:41:48.417
```

I want to sort by `transDate`, but I need to display just the date (without timestamp) - like this:

```
emp#     empName     transDate
-------------------------------
102       bbbb       2016-01-01 
103       cccc       2016-02-01
101       aaaa       2016-03-01
```

I tried this query:

```
select 
    *, convert(datetime, transDate) as transDate 
from 
    employee
order by 
    transDate
```

Comment: `convert(date, transDate)`

Comment: convert function will take "datetime" parameter only.

Comment: if i use "date", throws below error,  Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: `convert(varchar(10),transDate,121)`

Comment: If the original transDate is a DATETIME or any other temporal data type, DATE can be used in CONVERT in Microsoft SQL Server (as the tag and the title states it). If it is a string, well, why it is?

Comment: I see your problem (according to the comment in @SqlZim answer). You should state clearly that you want to ORDER BY the transDate of the table, and not the transDate of the result (because you alias the result as transDate) also. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: What SQL Server **version** are you running this query against?? Try running `SELECT @@Version` and let us know. The `DATE` datatype was introducted in SQL Server **2008** - if you should be on 2005 or even older versions, this won't be available to you

Answer (score 2):

Convert to DATE instead:

```
select *, convert(date,transDate) as transDate from employee
order by transDate
```

Comment: should not display time. i want only date part

Comment: Works for me, I am using SQL Server 2014 though. Which version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

Comment: It is the version of SQL Server that count, not the SSMS. If your version of SQL Server is 10.50.1600 ... , it is SQL Server 2008 R2, which should support the DATE data type as well as the CONVERT function. Google those key terms with T-SQL attached to it.

Comment: Looks like you're using 2008, which won't support my answer then... I would recommend looking at SqlZim's answer or see http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx for more convert options

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to distinguish the transDate of the table and of the resultset. The `ORDER BY` clause is processed last, hence it might have sorted by the transDate of the result set instead of the transDate of the table.

```
SELECT e.*,CONVERT(DATE, e.transDate) AS transDate
FROM employee e
ORDER BY e.transDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `convert(varchar(10),transDate,121)`

or: `cast(transDate as varchar(10))` if your `transDate` is already a *`char` type.

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select 
      emp#
    , empName
    , transDate
    , vc_converted=convert(varchar(10),transdate,121)
    , vc_casted   =cast(transdate as varchar(10))
    , dt_converted=convert(date,transdate)
  from (values
       (101,'aaaa','2016-03-01 15:41:48.417')
      ,(102,'bbbb','2016-01-01 15:41:48.417')
      ,(103,'cccc','2016-02-01 15:41:48.417') 
    ) as e(emp#,empName,transDate)
  order by transdate
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/KKTWZ53647

rextester results:

```
+------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| emp# | empName |        transDate        | vc_converted | vc_casted  |    dt_converted     |
+------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
|  102 | bbbb    | 2016-01-01 15:41:48.417 | 2016-01-01   | 2016-01-01 | 01.01.2016 00:00:00 |
|  103 | cccc    | 2016-02-01 15:41:48.417 | 2016-02-01   | 2016-02-01 | 01.02.2016 00:00:00 |
|  101 | aaaa    | 2016-03-01 15:41:48.417 | 2016-03-01   | 2016-03-01 | 01.03.2016 00:00:00 |
+------+---------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: If i use "convert(varchar(10),transDate,121)", it is not sorting data correctly

Comment: I'd be interested to see what the results look like when you use that. Can you post it?